# Efficient algorithm and storage format for the table 3xN

Tags: arrays, algorithm, storage, lexer, dfa

Given the following table:

```
|A|B|C|
|0|0|1|
|1|0|3|
|1|1|1|
|1|2|1|
|1|3|1|
|1|4|2|
|2|5|1|
```

I need to come up with the most efficient algorithm and storage format that will allow me, determine C given A and B:

```
                +-----------+
                |   BLACK   |
A = 0, B = 0 -> |    BOX    | -> 1
                +-----------+


                +-----------+
                |   BLACK   |
A = 1, B = 4 -> |    BOX    | -> 2
                +-----------+
```

Algorithm should provide good trade off between memory and efficiency. My first attempt was to make a hash out of A and B and use it as a key for the map:

```
{
    "0.0": 1,
    "1.0": 3,
    "1.1": 1,
    "1.2": 1,
    "1.3": 1,
    "1.4": 2,
    "2.5": 1
}
```

But I doubt that it's best approach (regarding the memory allocated for the such map, and lookup time, because this table can contain thousands rows).

Can somebody show me a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

A hash table sounds like a perfectly reasonable way to approach this, even for thousands of rows.  What language are you using?  How large is your table and what was the performance of your first attempt?

Are there patterns in your data you could use?  What are the possible ranges of A, B and C?

More data needed.

[This is a  comment not an answer but apparently I have insufficient reputation to post comments.]

Update to include an example for my nested-arrays idea:

```
var table = [];

function add_entry (A, B, C) {
  if (!table[A])
    table[A] = []; // create if it doesn't already exist
  table[A][B] = C;
}

function retrieve_entry (A,B) {
  return table[A][B];
}
```

This produces structures like:

```
table = [
  [ 1 ],
  [ 3, 1, 1, 1, 2 ],
  [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1 ]
];
```

Standard javascript arrays, being just objects in disguise, handle sparseness just fine.
Since I missed the part where B increases uniformly even when A changes (I thought B started back at zero each time),  if you use typed arrays you'd need to explicitly store a (typed array, offset) pair; you'd also need to work out the sizes beforehand.  This might be a bit messy, but should be perfectly doable.  It might or might not turn out to be more efficient, depending largely on how many C values you have per B value.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript. Table itself contains the data generated by my lexer generator, so it might very large. I didn't really measured the performance, just my thoughts was that it's not an ideal solution.

As I've mentioned, table - is transition table for finite automaton, so there is no patterns that can be used. A, B, C can range from 0 to 65535.

Comment: By the way, I didn't mention that A, B, C are continuous (0, 1, 2, 3, n), i. e. there is no gaps in those values)

Comment: Measure the performance! If it's not too slow there's no point in adding complexity to speed it up.

That said, and given that your values are consecutive: how about some Uint16Arrays? Make a Uint16Array with your B->C mapping (e.g. [1,1,1,2] for the case of A=1 above) then make an array of A values that point to the arrays of B values.

Comment: I didn't get it. How do I build this B->C mapping table? If I understand you correctly then I need to put all A values into one array, where indexes will represent A values and values will be the references to the second array that consists of a pairs B->C right? If so then it's not going to work because the relations between A->B as well is between B->C is not one to one, it's many to many, means that for A = 0 there are more than one pairs B->C. So it's not going to work with arrays if I understand your solution.

Comment: Ohh yeah, now I understand and yes, this will work but sparseness here will be an issue. I tried that before and found out that the final table consists of about 70% zeros.

Comment: Btw my version used one dimensional array instead of 3 - dimensions in your case. Since I know the ranges of A and B I can calculate one dimensional index smth like this: A * MAX_A + B.